# A little CUDA conundrum

Tags: cuda

I have array `A[0...N]` of `double` and array `B[0...N]` of `int`. Every `B[i]` varies in `[0...P]`. All I need is to calculate array `C[0...P]`:

```
C[j] = SUM( A[i] : B[i] = j)
```

I can't use `N` threads with `atomicAdd()` function since it does not support `double`, as far as I know. A straightforward implementation with `P` threads is highly divergent. Is there a better way?

Comment: +1 for the use of the word 'conundrum'

Comment: I think this is just a keyed reduction (i.e., use ```thrust::reduce_by_key```), but I can't figure out precisely what is meant by ```SUM(A[i] : B[i] = j)```. In any case, I wouldn't recommend ```atomicAdd```, even if ```A``` was of type ```float```. ```atomicAdd``` implies arbitrarily large serialization, depending on the distribution of values in ```C```.

Comment: The expression means that `C[j]` is the sum of all `A[i]` such that `B[i] = j`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to do a summation reduction of the double precision array `A` by the integer keys held in `B`. The [Thrust](http://thrust.github.io/) template library contains the [reduce_by_key](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#gad5623f203f9b3fdcab72481c3913f0e0) operation for this. The [sum rows](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/sum_rows.cu) example shows how to use reduce_by_key for a similar application, although it uses counting iterators to generate the key rather than using a user supplied key vector. It should be trivial to modify it to your needs.

Comment: Actually, you're quite right. Thank you for another answer on my question. The only problem left is to look into Thrust code and find out the algorithm implemented. This is not easy for a novice in Thrust.

Comment: @AdelNick: I would recommend using thrust directly. You can easily wrap an existing device memory pointer with a `thrust::device_vector` and call `reduce_by_key` in your host code. Thrust is included in the most recent versions of the CUDA toolkit (4.0 and the 4.1 developer preview) so you shouldn't need to install anything to use it.